# Obtener un array de objetos con una única propiedad de origen

Tags: angular, typescript

resumo de forma simple y breve.

Tengo el siguiente array de objetos:

```
a = [
   { id: 1, name: "nombre1"},
   { id: 2, name: "nombre2"},
   { id: 3, name: "nombre3"}
]
```

¿Existe alguna función predefinida que me permita extraer la propiedad "name" de la siguiente forma?

```
b = [
   { name: "nombre1"},
   { name: "nombre2"},
   { name: "nombre3"}
]
```

No puedo hacer

```
b = this.a.map(data => data.name)
```

porque me devuelve

```
b = ["nombre1", "nombre2", "nombre3"]
```

Muchas gracias de antemano y un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado, muchas gracias a los que lo han intentado.

La función a utilizar sería la siguiente:

```
b = this.a.map(data => ({name: data.name}))
```

Si además es necesario eliminar los duplicados, es de la siguiente forma:

```
b = this.a.map( data => data.name)
          .filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index)
          .map( data => ({ name: data }))
```

Un saludo

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).